# Collision detection does not work when controls are added

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics

I have a code that kind of detects collision, it works if I set the x and y away from the object which it detects collision from (I need to set it straight away from the code before I run the script)
If I add controls into it, and move it around while its running, it doesn't detect the collision.
Here is the code:

```
import time
import random
import sys
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('collision') 
wn.bgcolor('black') 
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

p_s = 20
e_s = 20

px = 0
py = 0
ex = 0
ey = 0
pec = 0

def collision():
    global pec
    pupc = px + p_s / 2 
    pdownc = px - p_s / 2
    pupcy = py + p_s / 2 
    pdowncy = py - p_s / 2

    if ex == px or ex > px and ex < pupc or ex == px or ex < px and ex > pdownc:

        if ey == py or ey > py and ey < pupcy or ey == py or ey < py and ey > pdowncy:
            pec = 1

        else:
            pec = 0

    else:
        pec = 0

    if pec == 1:
        print ('collision')

    elif pec == 0:
        print ('nope')

#enemy
e = turtle.Turtle()
e.goto(ex, ey)
e.speed(0)
e.color('red')
e.penup()

#player
p = turtle.Turtle()
p.goto(px, py)
p.speed(0)
p.shape('square')
p.color('blue')
p.penup()

print('move')
def p_up():
    py = p.ycor()
    py += 20
    p.sety(py)
    print(py)
    wn.update()
    collision()

def p_down():
    py = p.ycor()
    py -= 20
    p.sety(py)
    print(py)
    wn.update()
    collision()

def p_right():
    px = p.xcor()
    px += 20
    p.setx(px)
    print(px)
    wn.update()
    collision()

def p_left():
    px = p.xcor()
    px -= 20
    p.setx(px)
    print(px)
    wn.update()
    collision()



#keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(p_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(p_down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(p_right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(p_left, "Left")

#main part 
while True:
    wn.update()
```

Comment: Just edited it to fix a syntax error

Comment: Thanks! Works, but I'm not really clear what you're checking collision against. I see a blue square which I can move around, and on every tick I see "collision" printed. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? I'd expect to see some other object you'd want to collide with.

Comment: There arent graphics for the box that's being collided with yet, but in the the code, I have the box there. Try and change the variable px or py, the enemy size is set to 50 so if you change the x or y (of the player) it will say nope which means 'not collided' however, if you use the controls, and press up, down, side to side, and go far away, it still detects collision

Comment: So try and change the px and py to smth like 100

Comment: Sorry, these instructions and the sort of hard-to-understand variable names aren't really helping me figure out what the problem is. Can you edit the question to show how to reproduce the problem, and clearly explain the desired behavior? Adding graphics for the thing you want to collide with is simple to do and makes it a lot easier to tell if there's a collision or not. Ideally, I should be able to copy/paste/run the code and see exactly what's going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I added the graphics for the red box that's you will collide with. Now, for the variables. Px and py are the player positions, and ex and ey are the enemy position, e_s and p_s are the size of the box (but if you change the variable, it wont chnage the actual size, the code will just change, pupc is players top half collision , pdownc is players bottom half collision, pupcy and pdowncy are the same but with y instead of x, and pec is player-enemy collision.

Comment: The thing is, when I set the px or py to something away from the box (like 50) it detects that its away from the box, however, if I keep the px or py to 0, and move the player around with arrow keys, it doesnt detect that the player is away from the red box

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So, it looks like you want movement to be constrained on a 20px grid? Checking collision then on such a grid is a matter of `px == ex and py == ey`, so I'm having a hard time following the motivation for top/bottom halves and so forth. As for the current conditionals, keep in mind that `or` has higher precedence than `and`. But the main problem is that inside the `p_up`, `p_down` functions, `px` or `py` are purely local variables, so the global `px` and `py` vars never change and the initial collision state is permanent.

Comment: Having said that, just adding `global px` and `global py` in these functions is a poor fix, because it breaks function encapsulation and makes coding really difficult in the future. In fact, other functions already do this, so I'd add classes or at least have functions take arguments (parameters) and return values without modifying state. This might seem abstract and unrelated to the problem, but following practices like this sooner rather than later is a preventative measure that makes the program easier to debug and expand on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're making this problem more difficult than necessary.  First, turtle provides basic collision detection with the `.distance()` method.  Second, the only globals necessary are constants as we can always interrogate the turtle about it's current position (and heading, etc.):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600

def player_up():
    player.sety(player.ycor() + 20)
    check_collision()

def player_down():
    player.sety(player.ycor() - 20)
    check_collision()

def player_right():
    player.setx(player.xcor() + 20)
    check_collision()

def player_left():
    player.setx(player.xcor() - 20)
    check_collision()

def enemy_relocate():
    enemy.hideturtle()

    x = randrange(CURSOR_SIZE - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE)
    y = randrange(CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE)
    enemy.goto(x, y)

    enemy.showturtle()

def check_collision():
    if player.distance(enemy) < CURSOR_SIZE:
        print("Collision!")
        enemy_relocate()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.title("Collision!")
screen.bgcolor('black')

# enemy
enemy = Turtle()
enemy.shape('circle')
enemy.color('red')
enemy.speed('fastest')
enemy.penup()

enemy_relocate()

# player
player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.color('blue')
player.speed('fastest')
player.penup()

# keyboard binding
screen.onkeypress(player_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(player_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(player_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(player_left, 'Left')
screen.listen()

# main part
screen.mainloop()
```